# Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS): write release information to file?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've created a release definition in VSTS. After I deploy my application to the app service, I want to have the information about the release shown in my application. My application currently reads a file releaseinfo.json from the app_data folder which needs to be filled during the release process in VSTS.

Does anybody know how to get this information (like the release number and description) into the file from VSTS? Or is there another way to get this info into my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to save the release information in a file, for example, PowerShell programing.

There is the [Replace Tokens task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) that can do it easily, it can replace the token in the file (e.g. `#{releaseInfo}#`) to the variable value (e.g. `releaseInfo`), you can use the pre-defined variable, for example `Release.ReleaseId` (`#{Release.ReleaseId}#`).

Comment: I've tried this and it does work for the build definition, but it does not work for the release definition however. I've added a file with variables to the solution, but it can't find the file, I guess because the artifact file is a zip. I've tried replace tokens before and after the deploy of the azure app service. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @TedOnTheNet With azure app service deploy task, you can use JSON variable substitution (File Transforms & Variable Substitution Options). With Replace token task, you need to extract the zip file. On the other hand, you can upload additional files to azure web service through App Service deploy task (Uncheck Publish using Web Deploy option and specify the folder path of the additional files)

Comment: @TedOnTheNet What's the result now? Do you solve this issue?

Comment: No I haven't. Currently I have a file in the solution called releaseinfo.json which is simular to your suggestion. The problem is I use webdeploy thus I have a zipfile containing the solution and I guess that's why I cannot substitute the variables in the file. I NEED to use webdeploy, because that's the only way I can clean the existing files before deploying. If I don't clean up the environment,my app doesn't start anymore after a few deployments (I get initialization errors). How do I deploy additional tasks and put them in the app_data folder from the release definition?

Comment: With Azure App service deploy task, the JSON variable substitution can update the file in the zip file without need to extract the zip file, how do you set it? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive (Add System.debug variable with true value, then start release and share this log)?

Comment: I fixed it with the json variable substitution instead of replace tokens. I typed **\releaseinfo.json, but the format needed to be **/releaseinfo.json and then it worked! thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the release related info from the environment variables. You can read it in a powershell/bash task and write it back in the required format

See [the variables documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?tabs=batch) for more info